# write an array to the next column in a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science

```
landData = []
landData = pd.read_csv('Agriculture land area.csv')
landData = landData.drop(landData.columns[[0]], axis=1)
```

I currently have a CSV file that only have 1 column:

[image: only the first column is filled with years]\

I want to write my array landData to the second column after year but can't seem to find anything that works online.

Anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: You could do this, or you could read in the years, join your data into them, and write out the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might convert the landData DataFrame (read by read_csv) to a Series, then making that Series the column of the other DataFrame.

```
landData = pd.read_csv('Agriculture land area.csv')
landData = landData.drop(landData.columns[[0]], axis=1)

landData_Series = landData.loc[:,landData.columns.values[0]]

OtherDataFrame['NewColumnName'] = landData_Series
```

Make sure that both of the indexes (from landData_series and from OtherDataFrame) are the same, otherwise you would get NaN values.

Let me know if that helped :)

Comment: OMG it worked ! thank you so much ! I've been trying and trying for so many hours reading through all the documentations for pandas and to_csv. Thank you !!